# Menu splits and fixes to top when scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, scroll, fixed

My blog when you first visit the page. (actual screen shot)
[image: Webpage on first opening]

What happens when the user scrolls down (actual screen shot; nothing special happens at the moment)
[image: What happens currently when the user scrolls down]

This is what I would like to happen (edited screen shot).
[image: What I would like to happen]

Would someone please point me in the right direction to maybe a tutorial/ let me know what the term for this 'technology' is called. I'm sure it is possible to do this in jQuery/CSS but I am not sure what I need to search for.

I am running Wordpress and the *Michael Norris* is the Header text and the *Menu* is a navigation menu created by the Wordpress Menus editor.

Is there a plugin that will do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look for a few 'sticky' plugins using jQuery. http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: @JohnGerdsen Is there a way to do this incorporating it into Wordpress?

Comment: Mike, there may be a plugin that could convert your WP header & menu into a sticky type. Otherwise you will probably be faced with opening up the source files and adding these classes manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to detect the scroll event, which can be done using [**.scroll()**](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) in  jQuery
2. Once they started to scroll, you have to change the position to **`FIXED`** of the block of elements.  For this you can use [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

I think you have like this, if not try to wrap it in a div

```
<div class=wrapper></div>
<h1>Michael Norris</h1>
<ul>
 <li>Home</li>
 ....
 ....
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope you understand my logic.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I do understand, however I've edited my question to state that I am using Wordpress (I forgot to mention that before) and that may change things slightly...